# Xbee module works for 10 seconds

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am trying to communicate between 2 arduinos using 2 xbee shields. I am trying to configure the Xbee shield with PAN ID, address etc. I am using X-CTU utility on a windows 7 64 bit operating system. I am able to configure one of the XBee modules with all the necessary parameters. I am not able to repeat the same for the other module.

I able to communicate to the Xbee shield for the first 20 seconds. During this 20 seconds, the light on the Xbee shield is ON. The xbee shield responds to the communication query test and the serial number is verified. I am not able to repeat the query test after the light goes OFF. Is my XBEE shield broken?

Comment: Are you using sparkfun boards, and xbee Pros? I remember that sparkfun used a regulator that was too small to support the current draw of the xBee Pro at one point. That would somewhat correlate wit what you are seeing, as the regulator overheats and shuts down after a little while.

Comment: It seems that I did not program the modules correctly earlier. I had to hard reset and reprogram the xbee modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Noe enough information provided.

(2) Too much happening. Probably.

(3) If "I am not able to repeat the same for the other module." means, "ever in amy circumstancve when operated in the manner which allows the other one to work", then if the two are identical parts with identical configurations then one is, by definition (more or less) broken. Or both are. Otherwise,

(4) Xbee shield is probably not broken.

---

Re 20 second issue:

If this happens with bad Xbee only then work that out first.

If it happens with "good" xbee then somewhere there will be a boundary. You need to find it.

Do the absolutely minimum necessary to get interaction with the shield that you can detect (LED on or supply present or some signal occurring.
 THEN STOP.Let it sit. Does it "die" after or 30 seconds or one minute or more?

- If not, work up in complexity from there.
- If it does stop as before, work down in complexity and find what XBee directed activity (even with Xbee not being accessed) removes "stopping"

---

Comment: I got it working. I read a documentation to retrieve modules that have gone south during firmware programming. Thanks for the suggestions. I did try your above suggestions to narrow down the problem

Comment: @Sai Can I get the document you read I face the same problem